# Get first two rows from first two groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider the data frame `df`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    list('aaaabbbbbccdddddd'),
    list('tuvwlmnopxyfghijk')
], names=['one', 'two'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)

df

         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
    v      2
    w      3
b   l      4
    m      5
    n      6
    o      7
    p      8
c   x      9
    y     10
d   f     11
    g     12
    h     13
    i     14
    j     15
    k     16
```

How do I elegantly get the first two rows of the first two groups if I group by the first level of the index:

```
         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
b   l      4
    m      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
You could use a *list comp* and `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([g.head(2) for _, g in df.groupby(level=0)][:2])

         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
b   l      4
    m      5
```

Since having the list comp complete is an unnecessary overhead, you could use `itertools.takewhile` to prevent that.

```
it = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0] < 2, enumerate(df.groupby(level=0)))
pd.concat([g.head(2) for _, (_, g) in it])

         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
b   l      4
    m      5
```

---

**Option 2**
Another possible solution I could think of is pre-filtering your df to retain rows for only the first two values of index level 0, and then do the groupby.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900625/4909087
df.loc[df.index.levels[0][:2].values].groupby(level=0).head(2)

         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
b   l      4
    m      5
```

Comment: Your comprehension fully completes.  I wonder if there is a way to break it early.

Comment: @piRSquared Just got an option 2.

Answer (score 1):

Looks hacky but this is what I tried

```
df.groupby(level=['one']).head(2)[:4]


       col
one two 
a   t   0
u   1
b   l   4
m   5
```

Comment: Certainly, but cleaner than the list comp!